# Erlang result in accumulator

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to write a program that collects all Pythagorean triples equal to a given number; for example, calling `main(12)` should return `[{3,4,5}]`. But when I run my code, the answer is `[]`. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
-module(triples).
-export([main/1]).

t1(A, B, C) ->
    {A-2*B+2*C, 2*A-B+2*C, 2*A-2*B+3*C}.
t2(A, B, C) ->
    {A+2*B+2*C, 2*A+B+2*C, 2*A+2*B+3*C}.
t3(A, B, C) ->
    {2*B+2*C-A, B+2*C-2*A, 2*B+3*C-2*A}.

find_triples(A,B,C,Max,Acc) when (A+B+C) < Max ->
    if
        A+B+C == Max ->
            Acc = lists:append(Acc,[{A,B,C}])
    end,
    {A1,B1,C1} = t1(A,B,C),
    Acc = find_triples(A1,B1,C1,Max,Acc),
    {A2,B2,C2} = t2(A,B,C),
    Acc = find_triples(A2,B2,C2,Max,Acc),
    {A3,B3,C3} = t3(A,B,C),
    Acc = find_triples(A3,B3,C3,Max,Acc);
find_triples(_A,_B,_C,Max,Acc) ->
    Acc.
find_triples(Num) ->
    find_triples(3,4,5,Num,[]).

main(D) ->
    Answer = find_triples(D),
    io:fwrite("Wynik: ~w~n", [ Answer ]).
```

Comment: which algorithm you want to implement?

Comment: I use relation desribed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Parent.2Fchild_relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in the code you propose.

First, there is only one case in the if statement so if A+B+C is different from N it will crash (try with main(20)).

in the find_triple function you assign 4 time the variable Acc, remember than variable are not mutable in erlang.

Your code seem to be written only for the case when N = 12, although I don't see what is the algorithm you want to use.

You can solve this problem easily with list comprehensions. Let say you are looking for pythagorician triplet {A,B,C} where A > B > C > 0 ,A²==B²+C² and A+B+C == N.

Then A must be in the range 3 to N-2, B in the range 2 to A-1, and C=N-A-B with the conditions B > C and C > 0. lets write this in a list comprehention:

```
1> Pyt = fun (N) -> [{A,B,C} || A <- lists:seq(3,N-2), B <- lists:seq(2,A-1),C <- [N-A-B], B>C, C>0, B*B+C*C == A*A] end.
```

and try it:

```
2> Pyt(12).
[{5,4,3}]
3> Pyt(20).
[]
4> Pyt(90).
[{39,36,15},{41,40,9}]
```

Comment: for both variables I use the function `lists:seq(From,To)` that generate a list of integers `[From, from+1,...,To]`, then I use these lists as generator in the list comprehension :`A <- lists:seq(3,N-2)` and `B <- lists:seq(2,A-1)`.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the essence of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will accept it. I found solution by my self, version with list comprehension is extremly Inefficient, `Pyt(100000).` for example, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a call 2 part of function, that return Acc = [].
Should also note that all variables in Erlang immutably so you can not write:      `Acc =lists:append(Acc,[{A,B,C}])`